# which one is preferred? is or are

Tags: data-is-are

which one is correct in this sentence? is or are?
The robust stability and stabilization of uncertain linear systems  is/are investigated in this paper.

Comment: since you talk about 2 things I don't see why shouldn't you use "are". "x and y are investigated in this paper"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agree with "are". Substitute apples and oranges for your two nouns; it may make it more obvious.

Comment: Too simplistic an answer; arguably not totally correct. There have been many examples on ELU dealing with notional agreement of coordinated subjects, as with 'Health and safety is our primary concern.'

Comment: I should have used a better example - perhaps "apples and harvesting of apples". Still - I think "are" is preferable. I don't know what the initialism ELU means.